# Multiprocessing Event not Working

Tags: python, events, multiprocessing

I have written the following code in Python 3 using the multiprocessing module. It's more of a test script to see how to use `Event`. However, it's not working.

```
import multiprocessing, time

from multiprocessing import Process, Event

event = Event()

def f(n):

    if n == 1:

        print("starting")

        event.wait()

        print("Done!")


    if n == 2:

        time.sleep(3)

        event.set()

        print("setting")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p1 = Process(target = f, args = (1,))
    p2 = Process(target = f, args = (2,))

    p1.start()

    p2.start()

    time.sleep(1000)
```

However, when I run this I only get the output:

```
starting
setting
```

I want to get the output:

```
starting
setting
Done!
```

But for some reason the `p1` Process is not moving on with its code after event.set() has been called by the `p2` process.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I tested locally and it actually works, which OS platform are you using? Is it Windows?

Comment: I tried it again and it doesn't work! I got it to work once, but it doesn't work anymore. I'm on Windows. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I was answering the question but you canceled it... let me try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`multiprocessing` programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

> Explicitly pass resources to child processes
>
> ... it is better to pass the object as an argument to the constructor for the child process.
>
> Apart from making the code (potentially) compatible with Windows ...

On Windows, you need to pass the shared objects to the `Process` constructor list of arguments. Otherwise, the child process will get a brand new copy instead of the parent's one. This is why `f(1)` hangs, it is waiting on another `Event` object.

Just change the code like this.

```
def f(n, event):
    if n == 1:
        print("starting")
        event.wait()
        print("Done!")
    elif n == 2:
        time.sleep(3)
        event.set()
        print("setting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = Event()  # one instance of Event only

    p1 = Process(target = f, args = (1, event))
    p2 = Process(target = f, args = (2, event))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```