# Python Multiprocessing Semaphore not working

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, semaphore

I want my program to print out one line at a time, however it's printing multiple at a time and creating a garbled mess. I cannot seem to find out why the semaphore is not preventing multiple processes from printing over each other.

How can I get it to respect the semaphore?

Here is a simplified version of my code that has the same problem when run it (I'm running on Windows with Python 2.7.11 (this can't be changed)):

```
import multiprocessing

rightofway = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)

def writenum(number):
    rightofway.acquire()
    print("[+] - " + str(number))
    rightofway.release()
    return

def main():
    starting = 0
    ending = 50

    list = range(starting, ending)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    pool.map(writenum, list)
    return

#Required for Windows multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is an example of garbled output:

```
[+] - 0
[+] - 1
[+] - 2
[+] - 3
[+] - 4
[+] - 5
[+] - 6
[+] - 7
[[+] - 8
+] - 10[
+] - 9[+] - 11
[+] - 12

[[+] - 13+] - 14

[[+] - 15+] - 16

[[+] - 18+] - 17

[[+] - 19+] - 20

[[+] - 22+] - 21

[[+] - 23+] - 24

[[+] - 26+] - 25

[[+] - 27+] - 28

[[+] - 30+] - 29

[[+] - 31+] - 32

[[+] - 34+] - 33

[[+] - 35+] - 36

[[+] - 38+] - 37

[[+] - 39+] - 40

[[+] - 42+] - 41

[[+] - 43+] - 44

[[+] - 46+] - 45

[[+] - 47+] - 48

[+] - 49
```

Here's an example of the output I want (note I don't care about the order):

```
[+] - 0
[+] - 1
[+] - 2
[+] - 3
[+] - 4
[+] - 5
[+] - 6
[+] - 7
[+] - 8
[+] - 9
[+] - 10
[+] - 11
[+] - 12
[+] - 13
[+] - 14
[+] - 15
[+] - 16
[+] - 17
[+] - 18
[+] - 19
[+] - 20
[+] - 21
[+] - 22
[+] - 23
[+] - 24
[+] - 25
[+] - 26
[+] - 27
[+] - 28
[+] - 29
[+] - 30
[+] - 31
[+] - 32
[+] - 33
[+] - 36
[+] - 34
[+] - 35
[+] - 37
[+] - 38
[+] - 40
[+] - 39
[+] - 41
[+] - 42
[+] - 44
[+] - 43
[+] - 45
[+] - 46
[+] - 48
[+] - 47
[+] - 49
```

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: @tdelaney - Windows. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: I don't have windows handy, but this accepted solution uses an initializer with the pool. its my guess for the fix. a lock should work for you or adapt for semaphore  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664720/how-to-create-global-lock-semaphore-with-multiprocessing-pool-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @tdelaney - I attempted it and it resulted in exactly the same kind of garbled output. Lock isn't working either.

Comment: @tdelaney - Does the code work for you?

Comment: Yes, ... but I'm on linux so it'll be different.

Comment: @tdelaney - Ah, well, thanks for trying

Comment: It doesn't have this problem on linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961490/multiprocessing-event-not-working).

From the multiprocessing programming guidelines.

> Explicitly pass resources to child processes
>
> ... it is better to pass the object as an argument to the constructor for the child process.
>
> Apart from making the code (potentially) compatible with **Windows** ...

On Windows, you need to pass the shared objects to the Process constructor list of arguments. Otherwise, the child process will get a brand new copy instead of the parent's one. That's why you get the impression the `Semaphore` isn't working. The two processes are creating their own distinct `Semaphore` object instead of sharing the same one.

To pass a `Semaphore` object to a `Pool` on Windows you need to struggle a bit but not too much. As you cannot pass the `Semaphore` object to the `writenum` function directly, you need to rely on the `Pool` `initializer`.

```
from multiprocessing import Semaphore, Pool

mutex = None

def initializer(semaphore):
    """This function is run at the Pool startup. 
    Use it to set your Semaphore object in the child process.

    """
    global mutex

    mutex = semaphore

def writenum(args):
    with mutex:
        print "[+] - " + str(number)

def main():
    semaphore = Semaphore()
    pool = Pool(initializer=initializer, initargs=[semaphore])

    numbers = range(50)

    pool.map(writenum, numbers)
```

EDIT: just noticed I wrote about `Lock` instead of `Semaphore`. The core reasoning remains the same.

Comment: That worked! And I think I see why the code is that way, but lemme ask just in case. Why do we need to have mutex=None at the top even though it is declared in the initializer function? Also, why is the initializer function not a part of the Pool object?

Comment: Can you better explain what do you mean with the question `why is the initializer function not a part of the Pool object`?

Comment: It appears that Pool() is built to take arguments and bring them into the global space of the processes. If so, then why do I have to write part of that functionality myself instead of simply passing the (already global?) semaphore to the processes?

Comment: The `Pool` has two ways of passing data to child processes. The first is via the `apply`/`map` function arguments. This requires arguments to be pickleable and `Semaphores` are not. You can only rely on the second way which is by using the `initializer` function. As that function cannot return values, only way for your data to persist is by using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

To make things a bit easier, Following worked for me. Tested on Win10. 
**TL;DR - Use locks not semaphore**

```
import multiprocessing

rightofway = multiprocessing.Lock()

def writenum(number):

    with rightofway:
        print("[+] - " + str(number))

    return

def main():
    starting = 0
    ending = 50

    list = range(starting, ending)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    pool.map(writenum, list)
    return

#Required for Windows multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This isn't working for me for some reason. Same jumbled results.